# How to create commerce product content using date repeat entity module?

Tags: commerce, entities

I am using date repeat entity module in a content type say Movies to successfully clone the nodes.I also have a commerce product reference field in that content type which is working fine when I am not using repeat date.
I want to be able to create a new commerce product content for each node in the series when using repeat date.(while creating the Movies node I can see product fields like SKU,product title etc.)

For example,
I am creating a new Movies having start as 1st Jan 2016 and end date as 2nd Jan 2016.I want to repeat this event for every Friday till 31st Jan.
Now there will be 5 nodes created automatically.
how do i create a new commerce product content for each of these nodes?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you integrating with any third party system? Is there a specific reason for why you are recreating the nodes?

Comment: With regards to the Product entity being reference with the entity reference field, does this need to be cloned too or will you just be referencing the same product for each clone?

Comment: @nvahalik No,there is no third party system,just these modules.i want to create these nodes automatically( say each Friday for a year or two),each having add to cart available,each node may have different product title ,sku and price etc.

Comment: @AlexK yes,the product content needs to be different( different title,sku and price) which is referenced to each node.

Comment: Nodes don't have SKUs or prices—are you talking about creating a whole node/product combination, just the nodes, or just the products?

Comment: @nvahalik yes,nodes don't have SKUs but since i have given a reference of product to this content type i can see those fields(from commerce product type) while creating the node.If i don't give any reference then products will not be created automatically as nodes are.Also commerce product type (referenced to content type Movies) will be same for each node but the product content will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Date repeat entity module, but why don't you try implementing ***hook_node_insert()*** in a custom module, to handle creating a new product every time a a new node is created:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function my_module_node_insert($node) {

  //check type and that no product set previously
  if($node->type == 'my_type') {

    //create product
    $cp = commerce_product_new('product');
    $cp->is_new = TRUE;
    $cp->revision_id = NULL;
    $cp->uid = 1;
    $cp->status = 1;
    $cp->created = $cp->changed = time();
    $cp->sku = 'My SKU';
    $cp->title = 'My Product';
    $cp->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $cp->commerce_price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array(
      'amount' => 1000, //$10.00
      'currency_code' => 'USD',
    )));

    //save new product
    commerce_product_save($cp);

    //set reference field
    $node->field_product['und'][0]['product_id'] = $cp->product_id;

    //update node
    node_save($node);
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but this would be the general approach I would try.

This would only work if the Date repeat module invoked this hook though.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but I am not too familiar with creating or editing a module.Could you provide more detail please?How do u find the place to invoke in the entity module? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh OK, then I would recommend doing some tutorials on how to build your first module. There are plenty of great examples: 

https://www.drupal.org/project/examples
http://www.curveagency.com/blog/using-hooks

Comment: Okay so I followed your steps and went through that example,This code worked perfectly except I didn't use !isset because productid is already assigned everytime.Superb,Thanks a lot :)

Comment: great! glad I could help :) adjusted my answer code accordingly